# Add additional data series to tooltip on a highchart (possibly add layer to plot) in R

Tags: r, highcharts, tooltip, rcharts

Excuse my lack of clarity, as this is my first time using the rCharts, highcharts, or JavaScript for that matter.

My data frame is structured like this:

```
object    value     cum.value    date

 Dog       1           1         11-05
 Dog       3           4         11-06
 Dog      -2           2         11-07
 Cat       8           8         11-05
 Cat       3           11        11-06
 Cat       5           16        11-06
```

I currently have a highchart plotted in R, using this command:

```
chart <- hPlot(x = 'date', y = 'value', group = 'object', data = df, type = 'line')
```

I am trying to add a data series to my chart so that when you hover over each data point, it will show information that is not being plotted. Currently, it shows the date, the object, and the cumulative value.

I would like to add the cum.value to have it so if you hover over the chart on a point, it will show the date, the object, the value, and cum.value.

I tried looking into $tooltip, but I cannot seem to add more data series other than x and y, and I also lose the coloring scheme (if there is any way to preserve the default and only add the extra data series, that would be ideal).

Running this command removes the color scheme and I cannot seem to find a way to add the cum.value column.

```
chart$tooltip( formatter = "#! function() { return 'Date: '     + this.point.x + '<br />' + 'Cumulative Return: '    + this.point.y  + '<br />'; } !#")
```

As an aside, is it also possible to add a scatter plot layer on top of my line chart? So that the points of the scatter plot are the value, but the line in my chart is the cum.value.

I am not very verse at making graphs so any help would be appreciated. I would like to stay in R if possible as JavaScript is a bit daunting

Comment: How would you add an additional series value, but change it so that it is a different type (scatter) than the original (line)?

Comment: You could add series using [`chart$series`](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/demo/highcharts.R#L73-L75). If you will define each point as an object with named properties, then those properties will be accessible in tooltip's formatter from `this.point.<yourAdditionalProperty>`.